# Adjust tabulator row height

Tags: tabulator

I'm trying to adjust the table row height on a tabulator table. I'm trying to make the rows taller to make it easier to interact with for users on touchscreen devices.

I'm not finding anything in the documentation, and I haven't been successful adjusting the css. What is the proper way to make the rows taller? I'm trying to use Apple's suggestion of a 44px minimum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this in CSS by adjusting the cell padding, which by default is 4px

```
.tabulator-row .tabulator-cell{
    padding:8px 4px;
}
```

Make sure to include this after the tabulator stylesheet

Comment: If you make padding smaller than 4px, you also might decrease .tabulator-row min.height.

Comment: There is a typo in the previous comment, should be "min-height" instead of "min.height".     e.g.  .tabulator-row { min-height: 20px; }