# How to set header and row heights in Tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

For a custom React component I wrapped Tabulator and would love to support custom heights for a table header and indvidual rows. I only found row resizing in the [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/layout#resize-row), but no information about how to set a custom height in the data (or through an API call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question if you want to control the height of all rows or just particular ones.

If you want to control height based on data you can use a [row formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/print#formatters). Works well in my experience.

There is also this answer about overriding the [CSS for rows](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/dist/css/tabulator.css): [Adjust tabulator row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137943/adjust-tabulator-row-height)

```
.tabulator-row {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Right, I also used CSS to set a height for the tabulator-row class, however that's not the entire story. The text is then badly aligned and the hover effect on the header row shows a smaller rectangle. That means you would need to adjust a few more CSS classes, which together don't make this very dynamic. That's why I hoped there's an API.